# Rename Subfolders within the www-folder in Phonegap for Android, Windows Mobile and iOS?

Tags: android, cordova, path, directory-structure

Dear Ladies dear Sirs,

i have a short question as i am pretty new to phonegap and crossplattform programming. Unfortunately i already created an app with really many images and relations and changing the css and the html files affords much time. Additionally as one knows editing causes you creating new errors :-)

Thats why i have a question towards building/compiling with phonegap. Is it possible to rename the subfolders within the www folder?

I have my css file on the same "directorylevel" as the html file and my images folder is not called "img" but images.

Can i rename them within the www-folder or should i correct the paths within my html and css files?

Best Regards

Dimitri Petrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename subfolders all you like. Top level www folder and its subfolders are copied to platforms (android, ios, etc) by cordova cli automatically when calling the command `cordova prepare ios` etc..

In short, you can think of the www folder as a regular web app folder.